# <kbd> now looks faded! Why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> now looks faded across all the stack exchange sites! Just out of curiosity, What is the reason for it?

If I could find images of the previous `<kbd>`, I'll update the post!

Comment: Related [MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277646/kbd-value-is-grey-and-seems-to-be-disabled). It's in the process of being fixed.

Comment: Sorry! I did a search before posting this! I suppose google didn't crawl that question yet!

Comment: Don't worry, I'm sure it's the usual push-without-regression-testing migration. It'll get fixed with the usual migration-patch-migration!

Comment: The technology industry is moving toward speech recognition and wearables. Keyboard keys are now considered "deprecated" and should not be used for new projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been [completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277654/164200) and should be resolved in the next build.

As Hynes pointed out:

> The issue was a wrong color variable was selected for the text color.